# How do I build a desktop application with intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to build a command line app with intellij 8.1.  When selecting the project type I don't see anything that seems like it would fit. Am I missing something?

When building a web app it provides a src and an output dir etc.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Java module type for the command line Java applications. Build | Build Jars will help you to create an executable jar file which can be run from the command line:

```
java -jar jarname.jar
```

If you want Windows native executable, consider using some third-party tools like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Use ANT to build jar files and platform-specific bundles.